# Prove finding a spanning tree with no more than 50 leaves is NP-hard

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, trees, spanning-trees

This is a homework question. Consider the problem of finding if an undirected graph $G$ can have a spanning tree with no more than 50 leaves. Is this problem NP-hard?

I think it is and I'm trying to prove it. So far I've tried to reduce Vertex Cover to this problem. My idea is that the internal nodes of a spanning tree of $G$ form a vertex cover of $G$, but I'm stuck at trying to relate the internal nodes to the number of leaves of the spanning tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this problem is indeed $\text{NP}$-hard.

Here is a hint of proof. Draw several trees with 2 leaves. What kind of graphs are they?

Comment: They are paths.

Comment: Right. There is  a problem about finding a path that is also a spanning tree. What is that problem?

Comment: The Hamiltonian path problem?

Comment: I've come up with this. Let $s$ and $t$ be two nodes in $G$. Let $G'$ be a new graph made of $G$ plus 25 new vertices connected to $s$ and $25$ new vertices connected to $t$. Then, then the existence of a Hamiltonian Path in $G$ implies that there is spanning tree in $G'$ with at most 50 leaves. Is this correct?

Comment: Cool, that is correct.

Comment: God answer and following dialogue, but I think the answer will be even better off you incorporate the "dialog findings"